# java storing information into an object

Tags: java

This is probably going to be an easy thing but I am having a brain fart. I created an object

```
    Student s = new Student();
```

I need to store information in that object. I googled it and I can't find how to code it. I could post the full code but I want to do some of the work myself. I saw some posts online where people were using code I have not learned yet so I'm confusing myself.

Comment: try reading even the most basic java tutorial, this information is available in a billion places

Comment: Aren't you doing it here in your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003321/array-setting-length-and-storing-information

Comment: @sjr If it's in a billion places point me to one of them and I'll gladly read it because I'm not finding what I think I'm looking for.

Comment: This seems like a CompSci assignment and like in all assignments, they want you to learn about something and not just rushing to solve the assignment. Didn't your teacher provide you with any learning material, like a script? The very basics of java and at least some examples should be part of the course and the script. I'd recommend you to study that material which should be tailored to your course anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to have member variable in your `Student` class like :

```
String name;
```

then implement getter and setter :

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String aName) {
   name = aName;
}
```

and finally in your program :

```
Student s = new Student();
s.setName("Nicolas");
```

As this is the most basic stuff when it comes to OO programming, I'd really suggest you read some books and tutorial about Java.

Comment: `I want to do some of the work myself` lol the first time someone DOESNT just want the code

Comment: @talnicolas I did that then when I coded my program. I think there's more to it but I had asked my instructor for assistance I think now I realize where I was messing up. I appreciate the help. I know it was a poorly worded question but I was trying to get a clue to what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can make setter/accessor methods in the student class that set the value. Or use `s.[variable]` to access the variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

As posts and comments above have said, you should really read up on Java a bit more since that's a pretty basic problem to solve. But here's a little code snippet to give you a push in the right direction depending on what you need to do with your Student:

```
//The class name and visibility (also static or non-static if relevant)
public class Student {

//Variables, aka the data you want to store
String name;
double GPA;
boolean honorStudent;

//A setter method, setting a specific variable to a given value
public void setName(String input) {
    name = input;
}

//A getter method, returning the data you're looking for
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

//There would most likely be getters and setters for all
//of the variables mentioned above

//A lot of the time constructors are used to automatically
//set these variables when an instance of the class is created
public Student() {
    name = "My name!";
    GPA = 3.5;
    honorStudent = true;
}

//And of course if you want to make new students with custom
//data associated with them, you can overload the constructor
public Student(String newName, double newGPA, boolean newHonorStudent) {
    name = newName;
    GPA = newGPA;
    honorStudent = newHonorStudent;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

You will find the info you are asking about at the above link.
The Java tutorials are a terrific, free resource!